# Sliding image 4x4 with GridLayout

Tags: android, arrays, android-imageview, android-gridlayout

I want ask about sliding image puzzle.
below is code for slide to left or right.
but I have a problem.

```
  if (i + 1 < imageviews.size) {
                if (imageviews[i + 1]!!.drawable == null) {
                    mGridLayout.removeView(imageviews[i + 1])
                    mGridLayout.addView(imageviews[i + 1], i)
                    val temp = imageviews[i + 1]
                    imageviews[i + 1] = imageviews[i]
                    imageviews[i] = temp
                }
            }
            if (i - 1 >= 0) {
                if (imageviews[i - 1]!!.drawable == null) {
                    mGridLayout.removeView(imageviews[i - 1])
                    mGridLayout.addView(imageviews[i - 1], i)
                    val temp = imageviews[i - 1]
                    imageviews[i - 1] = imageviews[i]
                    imageviews[i] = temp
                }
            }
```

before do anything: [image: image1]
[image]

Comment: Look for `View` animation

Comment: Can you share full source code? It would be easier to implement what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated `setOnClickListener()` function and it seems to be working but I haven't solved it completely:

```
private fun setOnClickListener() {
    Log.i(TAG, "${imageviews.size} ")
    for (i in 0 until imageviews.size step 1) {
        imageviews[i]!!.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i(TAG, "${imageviews.size} $i")

            val top: Int? = if (i - GRID_NO >= 0) i - GRID_NO else null
            val bottom: Int? = if (i + GRID_NO < imageviews.size) i + GRID_NO else null
            val left: Int? = if (i % GRID_NO > 0) i - 1 else null
            val right: Int? = if (i % GRID_NO < GRID_NO - 1) i + 1 else null

            // Log.i(TAG, "Top: $top Bottom: $bottom Left: $left Right: $right")

            if (top != null && imageviews[top]!!.drawable == null) {
                imageviews[top]!!.setImageDrawable(imageviews[i]!!.drawable)
                mGridLayout.removeViewAt(i)
                mGridLayout.addView(imageviews[i], i)
                imageviews[i]!!.setImageDrawable(null)
            } else if (bottom != null && imageviews[bottom]!!.drawable == null) {
                imageviews[bottom]!!.setImageDrawable(imageviews[i]!!.drawable)
                mGridLayout.removeViewAt(i)
                mGridLayout.addView(imageviews[i], i)
                imageviews[i]!!.setImageDrawable(null)
            } else if (left != null && imageviews[left]!!.drawable == null) {
                imageviews[left]!!.setImageDrawable(imageviews[i]!!.drawable)
                mGridLayout.removeViewAt(i)
                mGridLayout.addView(imageviews[i], i)
                imageviews[i]!!.setImageDrawable(null)
            } else if (right != null && imageviews[right]!!.drawable == null) {
                imageviews[right]!!.setImageDrawable(imageviews[i]!!.drawable)
                mGridLayout.removeViewAt(i)
                mGridLayout.addView(imageviews[i], i)
                imageviews[i]!!.setImageDrawable(null)
            }
            if (isSolved()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success , true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED isSolved() FUNCTION UPON REQUEST**

Updated `isSolved()` looks like as follows:

```
private fun isSolved(): Boolean {
    var solved = true
    for (i in 0 until GRID_NO) {
        for (j in 0 until GRID_NO) {
            val index: Int = i * GRID_NO + j
            if (imageviews[index]!!.drawable == null) {
                continue
            } else if (imageviews[index]!!.drawable != imageViews[i][j]!!.drawable) {
                solved = false
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return solved
}
```

Please note that this version returns true if all cells except the empty cell in correct place, meaning that empty cell can be any cell at the end. If these kind of puzzles normally have more restricted success rules, like the empty cell should be on the corners, it needs to be updated.

Comment: I try this too, but I can check is puzzle is solved or not?
is there anyways to check itu?
I try

 `for(i in 0 until tempImage.size step 1){
if(imageview[i]!! == tempImage[i]!!){
solved = true} else {
solved = false
break}
}`

Comment: I mean I can't.

Comment: The question is about moving empty cell in correct way. The code above provides it. I haven’t go over how you check if it is solved or not. Do you say that isSolved() function doesn’t work properly?

Comment: isSolved() doesn't work properly, maybe you can make that method work properly?

Comment: I don't know criteria for exact successful finish but I also added updated version of `isSolved()`.